# mac Safari javascript fullscreen method doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, fullscreen

I'm having issues with Safari not going fullscreen as expected.

When the console is open or there are nav-bars around the container div, the fullscreen operation will show black bars where you would expect the console to be, or where the container should have expanded into.

Can this be resolved?

```
<script>
var fullscreen = () => document.getElementById('container').webkitRequestFullscreen()
</script>

<div id="container">
  <button onclick="fullscreen()" id="btn">FULL SCREEN</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/grantis/pen/ExXZNEg?editors=1111

Comment: Looks like it's just a Safari bug. It's leaving space for the console, but it's not actually showing it.